# How to select 2 values in SQL case statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider this query:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN identifier = 'V' THEN pos_x, pos_y 
    WHEN identifier = 'D' THEN height, weight
END 
FROM sprite_data;
```

This generates an error, because (how I understand it) the case statement can only return one value, but I am trying to return 2 values (pos_x and pos_y OR height and width). How can I make the case statement return two values?

Comment: Use two case statements.

Comment: @TabAlleman one after another, first one getting the pos_x ans second one getting the pos_y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a case return two values.  You can do this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN identifier = 'V' THEN pos_x    
    WHEN identifier = 'D' THEN height
END AS x,
CASE 
    WHEN identifier = 'V' THEN pos_y   
    WHEN identifier = 'D' THEN weight
END AS y
FROM sprite_data;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use printf in sqlite

Not tested:

```
printf ('%s, %s', pos_x, pos_y) as pos_xy
```

Comment: But that means I would have to parse the string for data afterwards which is not comfortable.